# Unexpected error in spring boot constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor

I wrote a sample program like below.

```
@Configuration
public class MyclassName{

    private final List<String> tableIds;

    public MyclassName(
        List<String> tableIds) {
        this.tableIds = tableIds;
    }
}
```

While running i am getting the below error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in MyclassName required a single bean, but 4 were found:
    - spring.sleuth.baggage-keys: defined by method 'baggageKeys' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.class]
    - spring.sleuth.local-keys: defined by method 'localKeys' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.class]
    - spring.sleuth.propagation-keys: defined by method 'propagationKeys' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.class]
    - spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys: defined by method 'whiteListedMDCKeys' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed


Process finished with exit code 0
```

We are using sleuth for tracing, so pom.xml has that dependencies aswell. But this is a very basic example, why iam getting this error. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The class `MyclassName` is known to the spring framework.

So spring will try to create an instance of `MyclassName` by using the constructor:

```
public MyclassName(List<String> tableIds)
```

The `Parameter 0 of constructor in MyclassName` is `List<String> tableIds`

Spring is trying to provide a value for this parameter but instead of only one available value, it founds 4. So Spring is not intelligent enought to choose one in your place.

The 4 available values are provided by Sleuth and are declared in the TraceBaggageConfiguration.class like follow:

```
@Bean(BAGGAGE_KEYS)
@ConfigurationProperties(BAGGAGE_KEYS)
List<String> baggageKeys() {...}

@Bean(LOCAL_KEYS)
@ConfigurationProperties(LOCAL_KEYS)
List<String> localKeys()  {...}

@Bean(PROPAGATION_KEYS)
@ConfigurationProperties(PROPAGATION_KEYS)
List<String> propagationKeys()  {...}

@Bean(WHITELISTED_MDC_KEYS)
@ConfigurationProperties(WHITELISTED_MDC_KEYS)
List<String> whiteListedMDCKeys()  {...}
```

To solve the indecision you need to tell Spring which `List<String>` you realy want injected in your constructor by using an unique identifier.

First qualify (give an id) to the expected bean

```
@Bean("myExpectedTableIds")
List<String> myTableIdsProcucerMethod()
```

Then use the `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` annotation to tell Spring which bean you realy want:

```
public MyclassName(@Qualifier("myExpectedTableIds") List<String> tableIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public MyclassName(
        List<String> tableIds) {
        this.tableIds = tableIds;
    }
```

This means that your `MyclassNames`, as a `Configuration` bean in `Spring`, needs to inject a bean of type `List<String>`, it happens that `slueth`'s `TraceBaggageConfiguration` class defines some beans of type `List<String>`:

```
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean({"spring.sleuth.baggage-keys"})
    @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties("spring.sleuth.baggage-keys")
    java.util.List<java.lang.String> baggageKeys() { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean({"spring.sleuth.local-keys"})
    @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties("spring.sleuth.local-keys")
    java.util.List<java.lang.String> localKeys() { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean({"spring.sleuth.propagation-keys"})
    @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties("spring.sleuth.propagation-keys")
    java.util.List<java.lang.String> propagationKeys() { /* compiled code */ }
```

So `spring` reported an error,  did not know which bean to inject. You may need to use `Qualifier` to specify the injected bean. Or, have you defined the corresponding bean which hash a  `List<String>` type need to be injected?  What is `List<String> tableIds` in your `MyclassName`? You need to define a `Bean` like this:

```
    public MyclassNamesss(
            @Qualifier("test") List<String> tableIds) {
        this.tableIds = tableIds;
    }

    @Bean("test")
    public List<String> myString() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Or you can use, in this case, the tableId will be `null`:

```
    public MyclassName(
            @Autowired(required = false) List<String> tableIds) {
        this.tableIds = tableIds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, and because I found this post looking for the same error message, I was doing this in Spring Boot, using Lombok
s `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to inject the `List<String>`:

```
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-prefix")
    public static class SomeProperties {
        @Getter
        private final List<String> patterns;
    }
```

and fixed it by initializing the list manually:

```
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-prefix")
    public static class SomeProperties {
        @Getter
        private final List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

the list was then correctly populated with the spring properties.